# Scaling PDF document generation on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I currently have an Azure VM hosting a C# Web Api app with some Word documents as embedded resources with bookmarks that are edited and then it generates a PDF document.

Basically what I need is to be able to call this service in parallel and generate thousands of PDF in less than 15 minutes. I cannot only increase the size of the VM because I don't need this service to be always available.

I would like to reproduce the behavior of an Azure function but with Word installed on the machine. How can I do that ?

EDIT : I am currently using OpenXml to edit the bookmarks

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docPath, true))
{
   EditAllBookmarks(document, config, data);
   document.Close();
}
```

Comment: why not use PDF generation on Azure functions?

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: @4c74356b41 because I cannot install word and use OpenXml with Azure functions. Do I need to change my code to generate PDF files from HTML instead of Word document ?

Comment: You could probably install Office in a WebRole (Cloud Services), although that seems a bit too much work. Either use a VM Scale Set or see if you can replace the Word installation with some interop C# NuGet/Office runtime/on idea what else but there has to be something lighter than installing full Office just to manipulate .docx.